# Using the cast and split string functions together in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to reshape my data, and in order to do this I need to cast it and split some strings.

No matter which way I try, I can't get the data to cast into the groups I require.  I don't know whether this is because it's not possible to do in one go, or if I'm fundamentally misunderstanding the functions.

My input looks like this:

```
input = structure(list(V1 = c("Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc"), V2 = c("Stacey", "Rachel", 
"Fiona", "Miriam", "Toby", "Steven", "Stacey", "Rachel", "Fiona", 
"Miriam", "Toby", "Steven", "Stacey", "Rachel", "Fiona", "Miriam", 
"Toby", "Steven", "Stacey", "Rachel", "Fiona", "Miriam", "Toby", 
"Steven", "Stacey", "Rachel", "Fiona", "Miriam", "Toby", "Steven", 
"Stacey", "Rachel", "Fiona", "Miriam", "Toby", "Steven"), V3 = c("PSY101_Summer_Results.Down", 
"PSY101_Summer_Results.Down", "PSY101_Summer_Results.Down", "PSY101_Summer_Results.Down", 
"PSY101_Summer_Results.Down", "PSY101_Summer_Results.Down", "PSY101_Winter_Results.Up_April", 
"PSY101_Winter_Results.Up_April", "PSY101_Winter_Results.Up_April", 
"PSY101_Winter_Results.Up_April", "PSY101_Winter_Results.Up_April", 
"PSY101_Winter_Results.Up_April", "PSY101_Summer_Results.Up_June_Resit.1", 
"PSY101_Summer_Results.Up_June_Resit.1", "PSY101_Summer_Results.Up_June_Resit.1", 
"PSY101_Summer_Results.Up_June_Resit.1", "PSY101_Summer_Results.Up_June_Resit.1", 
"PSY101_Summer_Results.Up_June_Resit.1", "PSY101_Summer_Results.Down_June_Resit.1", 
"PSY101_Summer_Results.Down_June_Resit.1", "PSY101_Summer_Results.Down_June_Resit.1", 
"PSY101_Summer_Results.Down_June_Resit.1", "PSY101_Summer_Results.Down_June_Resit.1", 
"PSY101_Summer_Results.Down_June_Resit.1", "PSY101_Summer_Results.Up", 
"PSY101_Summer_Results.Up", "PSY101_Summer_Results.Up", "PSY101_Summer_Results.Up", 
"PSY101_Summer_Results.Up", "PSY101_Summer_Results.Up", "PSY101_Winter_Results.Down_April", 
"PSY101_Winter_Results.Down_April", "PSY101_Winter_Results.Down_April", 
"PSY101_Winter_Results.Down_April", "PSY101_Winter_Results.Down_April", 
"PSY101_Winter_Results.Down_April"), V4 = c(-12L, -19L, -77L, 
67L, 64L, 33L, 25L, 73L, -42L, 95L, 24L, 2L, 7L, -54L, -87L, 
72L, 94L, -55L, 85L, 96L, -39L, -66L, -60L, -71L, 76L, 34L, 2L, 
-100L, -72L, 11L, 44L, -8L, -86L, -13L, -89L, 70L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-36L))
```

and I'm trying to get an output that looks like this:

```
output = structure(list(V1 = c("Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", "Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc", 
"Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc"), V2 = c("Stacey", "Rachel", 
"Fiona", "Miriam", "Toby", "Steven", "Stacey", "Rachel", "Fiona", 
"Miriam", "Toby", "Steven", "Stacey", "Rachel", "Fiona", "Miriam", 
"Toby", "Steven"), V3 = c("Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", 
"Summer", "Summer", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
"Winter", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer"
), V4 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "April", "April", "April", 
"April", "April", "April", "June_Resit.1", "June_Resit.2", "June_Resit.3", 
"June_Resit.4", "June_Resit.5", "June_Resit.6"), Up = c(76L, 
34L, 2L, -100L, -72L, 11L, 25L, 73L, -42L, 95L, 24L, 2L, 7L, 
-54L, -87L, 72L, 94L, -55L), Down = c(-12L, -19L, -77L, 67L, 
64L, 33L, 44L, -8L, -86L, -13L, -89L, 70L, 85L, 96L, -39L, -66L, 
-60L, -71L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

I can't seem to split and discard the parts I need, before casting.  Anyone got any tips that might help?

EDIT:  I can get close to the outcome you've described below (though the way Akrun describes below is significantly cleaner) but I'm having trouble then reassigning the bit of the string in V3 to the various columns. I'm trying to take V3 and split it into 2 parts (and seperate columns). The first new column would be whether it's Summer or Winter, the second would be whatever comes after the Up or Down (regardless of whether it's empty or not). The rest of V3 I could discard.

Comment: Sorry - I should've been clearer.  I can get close to the outcome you've described below (though your way is significantly cleaner) but I'm having trouble then reassigning the bit of the string in V3 to the various columns.  I'm trying to take V3 and split it into 2 parts (and seperate columns).  The first new column would be whether it's Summer or Winter, the second would be whatever comes after the Up or Down (regardless of whether it's empty or not).  The rest of V3 I could discard.

Comment: Can you pleasee update in your post

Comment: I've added the comment to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to extract the substring of interest with `str_extract`, then grouped by the columns, create a sequence column (`row_number()` - to take care of duplicate elements while `spread`ing`),`spread`to 'wide' format and`rename` the columns (if needed)

```
library(tidyverse)
input %>%
  mutate(new = str_extract(V3, "(Up|Down)"), 
         new2 = str_extract(V3, "Summer|Winter"),
         new3 = str_extract(V3, str_c("(", str_c(month.name,
                  collapse = "|"), ").*$"))) %>%
  select(-V3) %>% 
  group_by(V1, V2, new, new2, new3) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number())   %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  spread(new, V4) %>% 
  rename_at(vars(starts_with('new')), ~ str_c("V", 3:4)) %>%
  mutate(V4 = replace_na(V4, "")) %>% 
  select(-rn)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyr::extract` with appropriate `regex` and then `spread`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

input %>%
  extract(V3, into = c("season", "direction", "col"), 
              regex = ".*(Summer|Winter).*(Up|Down)_?(.*)") %>%
  spread(direction, V4)

#                                       V1     V2 season          col Down   Up
#1  Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc  Fiona Summer               -77    2
#2  Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc  Fiona Summer June_Resit.1  -39  -87
#3  Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc  Fiona Winter        April  -86  -42
#4  Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc Miriam Summer                67 -100
#5  Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc Miriam Summer June_Resit.1  -66   72
#6  Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc Miriam Winter        April  -13   95
#7  Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc Rachel Summer               -19   34
#8  Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc Rachel Summer June_Resit.1   96  -54
#9  Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc Rachel Winter        April   -8   73
#10 Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc Stacey Summer               -12   76
#11 Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc Stacey Summer June_Resit.1   85    7
#12 Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc Stacey Winter        April   44   25
#13 Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc Steven Summer                33   11
#14 Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc Steven Summer June_Resit.1  -71  -55
#15 Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc Steven Winter        April   70    2
#16 Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc   Toby Summer                64  -72
#17 Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc   Toby Summer June_Resit.1  -60   94
#18 Term1.PSY101_Summer_Results.report.doc   Toby Winter        April  -89   24
```